# Corona SDK - rectangle not appearing in expected place (coordinate system)

Tags: coronasdk, game-engine, coordinate

I'm brand new to corona SDK and following tutorials.  I notice that when I'm positioning elements theyre not appearing as they do in the tutorials.  For example:

```
local testRect = display.newRect( 0, 0, 50, 50 )
testRect:setFillColor( 0.5,0,0 )
```

[image]

In the tutorial it looks like this:

[image]

I would guess the anchor point on the rectangle would be 0.5, 0.5 and I'd have to position it 50% to the right, and 50% from the top of the upper left corner.  It looks like in their example the rectangle has an anchor point of 0, 0 and is stuck to the edge of the screen by default.

Why is there a difference?  i notice this tutorial is using an iphone 4.. but should that matter?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of years ago, Corona SDK went to their Graphics 2.0 standard. Part of this move was to get all display.* objects to behave the same when creating them. Before Graphics 2.0, some objects the X and Y values meant top left, for others it meant center. With Graphics 2.0, all X and Y values when creating an object are the center of the object now.

If you have an older tutorial, it may be assuming that the x, y is top left. In your example you are creating the object at 0, 0 which is the top left corner of the content area. Since you're on a screen that's wider than it's defined content area, 0, 0 isn't always the top left corner of the screen.

I'm guessing your config.lua is setting the width to 320 and the height to 480 (always listed as if the device was in portrait mode). But you're using an iPhone 5 screen, which means the top left corner is -44, 0. This explains why the image isn't all the way to the left edge.

Comment: How do you account for different screen sizes? Ideally you'd always want the top left corner of the screen to be 0,0 ..

Comment: There are several different ways to attack it. The have their pros and cons. One way is to calculate the top left using display.screenOriginX to add the extra space (usually a negative number)  to your locations to get to the screen's edge. See https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/screenOriginX.html.  The other options is to use a config.lua that computes your content area to make sure the content area fills the screen.  https://coronalabs.com/blog/2013/09/10/modernizing-the-config-lua/

Answer (score 0):

I am sure the anchor points they using are 0.5,0.5.

I suggest you check your build.settings file .. I tried the code and got the same result they had ..

[image]

Again CHECK your build.settings file